# Triple Integral of 6xy dV, why is lower bound of z 0 instead of 1?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

In the Stewart Calculus Textbook 7th Edition, problem 13 in chapter 15.7 states:

"Evaluate the triple integral:

Triple Integral within E of 6xy dV, where E lies under the plane z=1+x+y and above the region in the xy-plane bounded by the curves y = (x)^(1/2), y = 0, and x = 1"

I was able to solve it and found the answer using the bounds 0 <= x <= 1, 0 <= y <= (x)^(1/2), and 0 <= z <= 1 + x + y. What I don't understand though is why the lower limit for z is 0 instead of 1. When I thought about it, if the lower limit of z is 0, then that means, following the plane of z = 1 + x + y, at z = 0, the values for either x or y will be below their own lower bounds of 0 (since one or the other must be negative at some point). Could someone please explain why the lower bound can be 0 in this case? Thank you very much.

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1):

The *lower* bound is the region in the $xy$-plane, where $z=0$.  The *upper* bound is the surface $z = 1+x+y$.